# My class will return undefined if I call its method

Tags: javascript, html

what I'm trying to do is a class that creates an object, appends other objects and adds content to it without having to write several lines of

```js
var obj = document.createElement('input');
obj.value = 'this value';
obj.appendChild(anotherObject)
```

here is the code:

```js
class gerarNode{
    constructor(input){
        this.nodetype = input;
        this.node = document.createElement(input);
    }
    toAppend(appends){
        this.node.appendChild(appends);
    }
}
```

what I expect in the browser console:

```js
var jorge = new gerarNode('div').toAppend(anotherNodeObject)
// Object {"nodetype": "div", etc, etc}
```

what I get:

```js
var jorge = new gerarNode('div').toAppend(anotherNodeObject)
// undefined
```

but the weirdest is, if I call only the constructor method, it will return a "div" object just as I wanted, it just not works if I call any method in the class

```js
var jorge = new gerarNode('div')
// Object {"nodetype": "div"}
```

Comment: Why do you expect that? You have no `return` statement in `toAppend()`, so it returns `undefined` by default.

Comment: Even if I put ```return this.node``` in the toAppend() method it doesn't return anything

Comment: That would indicate `this.node` is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't execute a `return` statement in a function, it returns `undefined`.

To implement a fluent interface, all the modification functions should return `this`.

```js
class gerarNode {
  constructor(input) {
    this.nodetype = input;
    this.node = document.createElement(input);
  }
  toAppend(appends) {
    this.node.appendChild(appends);
    return this;
  }
}

let anotherNodeObject = document.createElement("div");
var jorge = new gerarNode('div').toAppend(anotherNodeObject);

console.log(jorge);
```

Comment: it doesn't return anything. the object type continues to be "undefined" and it returns "undefined" in the browser console

Comment: I added a snippet that shows that it returns what you expect.

Comment: now I understand! I tried something similar and it didn't work ``` return this.node ``` and then it returned undefined. Thank you

Comment: That shouldn't return `undefined`, either, but it doesn't return what you want.